# Converting raster to vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vectorization

I have reclassed my data so show areas were wind speed is greater than 5m/s and were it is not.

I have  converted this raster file to a vector file however it showing as one single colour and not defining between the white and black separated boundaries in the raster file.

I have looked at the style menu and tried to change the colours but nothing seems to work.[image]

[image]

Comment: The title is different from the content of the text. Do you want to style your polygon based on their pixel values or do you want to convert raster to polygon? If you want to convert raster to polygon then you need to use polygonize tool. Search for Polygonize tool in the processing toolbox and convert the raster to polygon.

Comment: sorry for the poor phrasing I am new to the software. I have already polygonised it from raster to vector, however it shows as one single colour after I have done so. I am now wanting to syle it based on pixel values

Comment: I am wanting it to show the same black and white colours as it did before in the raster file which was black for areas below 5/ms and white for areas 5m/s and above

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would help to need to mine the comments for information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your raster cell values are now stored in the vector layer as attributes, all you need to do is style the vector layer.

1. Select the vector layer in the Layer panel, and open the Layer Styling panel. Choose "Rule-Based" style from the dropdown menu.
2. Add a new rule based on the attribute table field where the raster cell values are stored. Substitute the actual field name into this expression where it says `rastervalue`:

   ```
   "rastervalue" < 5
   ```

   [image]
3. Add a second rule for `"rastervalue" > 5`
4. Style the first rule with black fill, and the second rule with white fill. Make the boundaries 'no pen' if you don't want to see an outline around every polygon.

[image]

This topic is explained in more detail in the QGIS training manual, [Lesson 4.3.5: Rule Based Classification](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification).

Comment: I have included pictures of each file. when I follow your instructions it highlights different areas in black to what is shown in the raster

Comment: @TomHaywood as I can see in your screenshot your rastervalues go from 0 to 0.999. You might want to try with these values. E.g. `"rastervalue" <= 0.5` and `"rastervalue" > 0.5` or whatever matches your windspeed correctly.